# intersection between two curves in Mathematica

Tags: graphics, numerics

I have two curves (drawn from points) in a plane, one is drawn with `ListLinePlot` and the other drawn with `ParametricPlot`. How can I determine the intersection between both curves? I cannot use (don't know how to) interpolation directly, since the curves are not graphs.

Let's say we have

```
 r[ϕ_] = 1 + 1/20 Sin[20 ϕ]; 
 tb = Table[{r[ϕ] Cos[ϕ], r[ϕ] Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π, 0.1}];
 ListLinePlot[tb]
```

and we interpolate data stored in `tb`. E.g. at `x = 0.95` there are 4 (or 5) different values for `y`. How can I plot interpolating function? I am sure I am missing something. Theoretically, I could use interpolation across segments of points on a curve but this is something I want to avoid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interpolation should work.  Could you post two example curves to work with?

Comment: Hi, Szabolcs. Thank you for your response. Let's say we have r[\[Phi]_] = 1 + 1/20 Sin[20 \[Phi]];
tb = Table[{r[\[Phi]] Cos[\[Phi]], r[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Phi]]}, {\[Phi], 0,
     2 \[Pi], 0.1}];
ListLinePlot[tb] and we interpolate data stored in tb. E.g. at x = 0.95 there are 4 (or 5) different values for y. How can I plot interpolating function? I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: Please don't post additional information concerning your question as a comment. Please add the info to your original question by making an edit.

Comment: you mean `ListPolarPlot`? (there isn't any built-in function named `PolarParametricPlot`)

Comment: @kguler of course. My mistake.

Comment: do you need an approach that works with tabular data or can you use the actual function?   If you interpolate the tabular data you of course end up with an approximate solution.  I only see one curve in your example by the way.

Comment: Generically, if two curves are given by $(x,y) = f(s)$ and $(x,y)=g(t)$, you solve $f(s)=g(t)$ for parameter values $s$, $t$.  Just how to set that up in *Mathematica* might depend on how the particular curves $f$ and $g$ are defined.  (Which is why you're being asked for more information.)   You might use `FindRoot` or `NSolve` for instance.

Comment: @george2079. I have only tabular data. The function is just an example. Can I interpolate tb in the example easily?

Comment: If you need *linear* interpolation for tabulated values of `r`, you can do `tab = Table[{phi, r[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}]` to compute tabulated values, then `tab = Table[{phi, r[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}]` to get the interpolating function.  Note that this is linear interpolation, i.e. made of line segments (I think that is what you want): `tab = Table[{phi, r[phi]}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi, .1}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question.

If you interpolate the data stored in table tb, you will get a function of x instead of φ.

Maybe this could work for you:

```
tb2 = Table[{φ, r[φ Cos[φ], 
r[φ] Sin[φ]}, {φ, 0, 2 φ, 0.1}]; (* just added φ to the list *)
intb = Interpolation[tb2[[;;, 1 ;; 3 ;; 2]]]; (* interpolation of y[φ] *)
inta = Interpolation[tb2[[;;, 1 ;; 2]]]; (* interpolation of x[φ] *)
ParametricPlot[{inta[φ], intb[φ]}, {φ, 0, 2 π}]
```

Perhaps someone could provide a much more elegant solution but this one is easy and it should work!

Comment: @ Gregory Rut   Thanks.